# How to concatenate few maps?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl, merge

I have few maps `std::map< char, int >`

```
First map:
a - 1
b - 2
c - 3

Second map:
a - 5
c - 6
e - 7
```

I want to concatenate them into `std::map< char, std::vector< int > >`

```
a - 1 5
b - 2 0
c - 3 6
e - 0 7
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Sometimes you need to write code.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) algorithm. Unfortunately, the value types of source and destination ranges are not compatible, so we need something that'll convert it for us. Boost provides a nice facility for this with [Function Output Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html). Whatever gets assigned to this output iterator is passed as an argument to the unary function it wraps. Together with lambdas, this is quite straighforward:

```
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

std::map<char, int> m1 { {'a',1}, {'b',2}, {'c',3} };
std::map<char, int> m2 { {'a',5}, {'c',6}, {'e',7} };

std::map<char, std::vector<int>> m3;

typedef std::map<char, int>::value_type source_type;
auto push_value =
    [&m3](const source_type& p) { m3[p.first].push_back(p.second); };

std::merge(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end(),
    boost::make_function_output_iterator(push_value));
```

This isn't quite what we wanted, yet. `m3` looks like this:

```
a - 1 5
b - 2
c - 3 6
e - 7
```

For the keys that are in `m2` but not in `m1` we need to squeeze a zero at the front of the vector. We can do that with [`set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) before we do the merge. We need to use custom comparator that only compares the keys of the maps:

```
auto push_zero =
    [&m3](const source_type& p) { m3[p.first].push_back(0); };
auto cmp =
    [](const source_type& p1, const source_type& p2) { return p1.first < p2.first; };

std::set_difference(m2.begin(), m2.end(), m1.begin(), m1.end(),
    boost::make_function_output_iterator(push_zero), cmp);
```

`m3` is now:

```
a - 1 5
b - 2
c - 3 6
e - 0 7
```

In third step we add a zero the for the keys that are in `m1` but not in `m2`:

```
std::set_difference(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end(),
    boost::make_function_output_iterator(push_zero), cmp);
```

Now we have what we wanted:

```
a - 1 5
b - 2 0
c - 3 6
e - 0 7
```

See the full example on [LiveWorkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/OhYSP%241).

Comment: +1 this is so much more convenient than my own 2-step explicit for loops.

Answer (score 2):

The naive way would be to first add all keys in the destination map. Then for each key in destination map add the corresponding value from the first map, if the key is not found then add zero. Then do the same with the second map.

Comment: Yeah. This is what came to my mind first, but instead of adding zero I thought about using vector::resize().

Comment: It may be smart to call `.reserve(NumMaps)` on each `vector` added in step 1. You know exactly how big they'll become.

Answer (score 0):

How about helper functions like this:

```
void one_map ( const std::map <char, int> &source, std::map<char, std::vector<int> > &dest, size_t idx )
    for ( auto const &p : source )
        dest [ p.first ] [ idx ] += 1;
    }

void fill_map ( const std::map <char, int> &source, std::map<char, std::vector<int> &dest , const std::vector<int> &zeroes ) {
    for ( auto const &p : source )
        if ( !dest.find ( p.first ))
            dest [ p.first ] = zeroes;
    }
```

Then you can write:

```
std::vector<int> z (3, 0);  // three zeros
fill_map ( a, dest, z );
fill_map ( b, dest, z );
fill_map ( c, dest, z );

one_map  ( a, dest, 0 );
one_map  ( b, dest, 1 );
one_map  ( c, dest, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's a simple no boost solution that may run a little faster (not in big O, but in total # of iterations):

```
   std::map<char,int>::iterator i,j;
   i = m1.begin(); j = m2.begin();

   while (i!=m1.end() || j!=m2.end()) {
      if (j==m2.end() || (i!=m1.end()&&(i->first < j->first))) {
         m3[i->first].push_back(i->second);
         m3[i->first].push_back(0);
         i++;
      } else if (i==m1.end() || (i->first > j->first)) {
         m3[j->first].push_back(0);
         m3[j->first].push_back(j->second);
         j++;         
      } else if (i->first == j->first) {
         m3[i->first].push_back(i->second);
         m3[j->first].push_back(j->second);
         i++;j++;
      } 
   }
```

Can probably be simplified to reduce the # of lines of code since the push_backs are done 3 times  each (3 different cases)....

The run time here is (# in m1)+(# in m2)-(# in both).  In all likeliness, this is roughly equal to a single set difference (or a single merge).

[Liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9Rc1z%2412)